# foreach (ManagementObject user in users) doesn't seem to be retrieving all local accounts

Tags: c#, local, user-profile

I use the following method to get all LOCAL user accounts on a machine. It finds 12 of them, but only processes the first one.

```
 ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile");
 ManagementObjectSearcher usersSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
 ManagementObjectCollection users = usersSearcher.Get();
    
 Console.WriteLine("Users: " + "[" + users.Count + "]"); // Reports 12
       
      
 foreach (ManagementObject user in users)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Checking User: " + GetNameFromSID(user["SID"].ToString()));
 }
```

It seems that it used to report all accounts. Is there a surefire way to get this information?

Comment: You mean this code was working fine previously but now it is not? Did you debug the code? Is there any exception? `GetNameFromSID` what's the use this method? Can you share code of that too?

Comment: What does *It finds 12 of them, but only processes the first one* mean? What *processes* the Profile? Are you referring to your `GetNameFromSID()` method? Are you using [LookupAccountSid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw)?